# SQLAlchemy won't connect correctly but pyodbc and pymssql will

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have been trying to diagnose the issue in a Windows Python 2.7 (Anaconda installed) environment running SQLAlchemy=1.1.11, pyodbc=4.0.17, and pymssql=2.1.3.

Both pyodbc and pymssql connections will successfully connect and query a table correctly.  However, when I attempt the same connection and query through SQLAlchemy either using an ORM or direct SQL, it fails with the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column '0'

The connection string I'm using is the following:

```
'mssql+pyodbc://:@CMPDSQL01:1433/CMP?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0'
```

The connection and simple query through pyodbc uses the following:

```
print "---- Testing pyodbc Directly"
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};'
    r'SERVER=CMPDSQL01;'
    r'DATABASE=CMP;'
    )

print cnxn
print "---- Complete ----"

print "---- Running Direct SQL Query on pyodbc Direct Connection"
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM EPO_MODELS')
for r in cursor:
    print r
print "---- Complete ----"
```

The connection and simple query through pymssql uses the following:

```
print "---- Testing pymssql Directly"
cnxn = pymssql.connect(server='CMPDSQL01', port='1433', database='CMP')
print cnxn
print "---- Complete ----"

print "---- Running Direct SQL Query on pymssql Direct Connection"
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM EPO_MODELS')
for r in cursor:
    print r
print "---- Complete ----"
```

What is even more perplexing is that the SQLAlchemy connection used to work but now no longer works.  Unfortunately I don't know what broke it due to a clean start install.

I don't think the EPO_MODELS object model comes into play with this error because even a direct SQL query fails in the same way.  However, for completeness the EPO_MODELS object model is very simple and looks like the following:

```
class EPO_MODELS(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'EPO_MODELS'

    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    MODELTYPE = Column(Integer, autoincrement=False)
    MODELNAME = Column(NVARCHAR(255))
    MEMO = Column(NVARCHAR(2000))
    NEXTUNIQUEID = Column(Integer, autoincrement=False)
    MODELSYNC = Column(Integer, autoincrement=False)
    MODELSTATUS = Column(Integer, autoincrement=False)
    AUDITUSERID = Column(Integer, autoincrement=False)
    DATEALTERED = Column(DateTime)
    CREATIONDATE = Column(DateTime)
```

The direct SQLAlchemy query looks like the following after getting the session using the connection string above:

```
print "---- Running Direct SQL Query Through SQLAlchemy Connection"
result = con.execute('SELECT * FROM EPO_MODELS')
for r in result:
    print r
print "---- Complete ----"
```

Very much appreciate any insight into what is going on here.  I can't seem to find the disconnect. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some diagnosis on the SQLAlchemy mailing list it looks like this is caused by the c extensions not being compatible with the server.  After removing the **cresultproxy.pyd** file from the sqlalchemy directory in site-packages the issue was resolved.

A pip uninstall/install did not fix the issue since the extensions were rebuilt during the install.  The c extension build did not emit any warnings or errors.  It just looks like this might be an edge case of an old Windows Server 2008 server configuration not working properly with the c extensions.